# Logging SOAP API Operations with PayPal Payments Pro

Tags: paypal

Should I save to the database the SOAP request that I am sending to paypal when executing the DoDirectPayment API?
I am concern about the Credit Card details written in the SOAP request as well as the PayPal API credentials. But are there any reasons why should I save the SOAP request?

Please help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to log all of my API calls so that I can refer to them if anything goes wrong or doesn't seem correct for some reason or another.

You'll definitely want to mask out the values for sensitive data like the CC number, cvv2 code, and expiration date in the request, though.  I do the same for the API credentials, too.

Comment: So does it mean, you are storing the SOAP Requests and responses in the database? (with credentials and other sensitive info masked?)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  <Like>****</Like><this>****</this> for the values that are sensitive.